# How to proof homeomorphism between open ball and normic space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

How can I prove that an open ball $B$ in a normed vector space $X$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

Comment: Can you do it for Euclidean space?

Comment: Can you do it in $\mathbb{R}$? You can take a _very_ similar homeomorphism in the general case.

Comment: not in R, just a normed space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality take the ball to be the unit ball $B = \{x ∈ X;\; \lVert x \rVert < 1\}$ around Null. (Translations and homotheties are homeomorphisms.)
Then the two maps
\begin{align*}
 X → B,\, x ↦ \frac{x}{1 + \lVert x \rVert},
 \quad \text{and} \quad
 B → X,\, x ↦ \frac{x}{1 - \lVert x \rVert}
\end{align*}
are continuous and inverse.

Comment: thanks it works
i also found that X -> tan(|x|)*x will do it

Comment: @k.stm How to find the inverse of this function?

Comment: @MathewGeorge Both the function and its inverse are mentioned in the post – what do you mean?

Comment: sorry I did not notice that it was the inverse.